# ADO.NET Performing a partial Update / Insert

Tags: sql, ado.net

I have been working with ORMs the last couple of years, and, on a personal project, am frustratingly finding myself struggling with simple ADO.NET.

I have a database with tables storing both transactional and slowly changing data. Data to update / insert is sourced via the network.

I am trying to use the disconnected Data Adapter paradigm in ADO.NET, in relatively generic DB classes to allow for many / all ADO.NET database implementations.

My problem is, due to the potential size of the database tables, I don't want to perform an Adapter.Fill into memory (as pretty much *every* reference and tutorial will demonstrate), rather use a delta DataSet to store push new / modified data back to the database.

If I peform a DbDataAdapter.FillSchema on a DataSet, I get a schema, and data tables I can populate, however all data, regardless of what I pass to my key fields, is treated as a new row when I update the table using Adapter.Update.

Am I using the correct ADO.NET classes to perform such a batch UPDATE / INSERT (by "batch" in terms of my not having to do it in a loop, rather than what any given database may be actually performing under the lid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be the RowState of the data row.

When a DataSet is filled through the DataAdapter, changes to existing and existing rows will set the row's RowState to modified.

Data that is added to the DataSet is seen as a new row, and its RowState will be set to Added.

RowState is a read only field, so it can not be manually set to Modified.

Therefore, all updating data received from a client should be added as follows:

```
// ... where dataTransferObject.IsNew == false 
DataRow row = table.NewRow();

row["Id"] = dataTransferObject.Id;//Set Key fields on row

table.Rows.Add(row);//Add row to table            

row.AcceptChanges();//change RowState to Unchanged

row["MyData1"] = dataTransferObject.MyData1; //Set other fields in row
row["MyData2"] = dataTransferObject.MyData2; //Set other fields in row
row["MyData3"] = dataTransferObject.MyData3; //Set other fields in row
```

I am also ignoring the CommandBuilder and hand crafting my Insert, Update and Select statements.

This data can now be persisted to the database using adapter.Update

I aknowledge that this is far from an elegant solution, but a working one.  I will update this answer if I find a nicer method